# Duplication Rule with Odd Behavior in Salesforce Flow

Tags: apex, visual-workflow, duplicate-management

I am experiencing some odd behavior with a salesforce flow I have built. I have two questions regarding this.

First, I have a duplication rule that is preventing new records from being created in my 'Create Records' flow element. This is odd, because I have the 'Allow' configuration set for the create and edit actions. I also have the 'Alert' and 'Report' for both create and edit configurations selected - after experimenting, it seems that the 'Alert' configuration is causing the creation of the records in the flow element to fail, EVEN THOUGH I have allowed the creation of the records in the duplication rule. Why is this happening?

Second, I am running into some odd behavior with this failure of record creation. Considering that the create records element is running a batch of records through (I have built some custom processes with apex to force the batch sizes to be 50 records), it seems that only the records that experience the duplication error are not being created - otherwise it IS created. This is odd to me, because I was under the impression if ANY records failed in a batch in a create records element, the ENTIRE BATCH was rolled back and none of the records were created.

This is further confusing because I am updating other records later in the flow, and this is NOT happening AT ALL - this makes it seem that since some of the records in the create record element failed, the flow is not continuing. This makes sense and confirms my understanding that even a single record failure in a batch will stop the process. So, why are some of the records being created? Just to summarize this point, it seems that the create records element is PARTIALLY successful, then the rest of the flow fails. This behavior does not make sense to me.

I have been unable to find any documentation regarding how duplication rules affect flows, specifically if the ALLOW feature is configure on record creation. I sure would appreciate some help on this!!!